# Disable gd library on a specific website

Tags: php, configuration, .htaccess, php5-gd

I am trying to disable gb library on a specific website so it won't affect the other websites which are hosted on the same server.

Is it possible to do this with htaccess or is there another way?

Comment: Is there an actual reason you're trying to do this?

Comment: The GD library on the specific site messes up a lot of things. Plus I am curious if this can be done with htaccess.

Comment: Are you using any control panel by any chance, such as Cpanel, Webmin or so on?

Comment: @Vicky I'm using Virtualmin/Webmin